# escaping % in Python IMAP lib

Tags: python, imap, imaplib

I'd appreciate help with how can I circumvent IMAP UID SEARCH for Message-ID containing % (percent) sign:

```
import imaplib

messageId = '<CA824955.19602%username@hostname.com>'
M.uid('search', None, 'HEADER', 'Message-ID', "'" + messageId + "'")
```

getting:

```
51:55.73 > EKEE4 UID SEARCH HEADER Message-ID '<CA824955.19602%username@hostname.com>'
51:55.83 < EKEE4 BAD Could not parse command
51:55.83 BAD response: Could not parse command
```

I've tried

```
CA824955.19602%username@hostname.com
'CA824955.19602%username@hostname.com'
'CA824955.19602\%username@hostname.com'
'CA824955.19602%%username@hostname.com'
```

with or without quotes all were returning same "Could not parse command".

Server is imap.gmail.com

Thank you,

PS:
Thanks much @glglgl, wrapping it into `'"' + messageId + '"'` actually helped. I'm getting messageId from mysql string field, for some reason it didn't work without this wrapping... 
Question is solved, thank you very much for lightning speed answer!!!

Comment: Try to see on high level libs, my - https://github.com/ikvk/imap_tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see your problem.

```
import imaplib m=imaplib.IMAP4_SSL([...]) m.login([...])
m.select('Archiv/misc') m.uid('search', None, 'HEADER', 'Message-ID',
   '<1i6c6x0.inv6rk1u5kx5cN%68kmac@gmail.com>')
```

works perfectly for me.

Have you already tried to omit the `"'" +` and `+ "'"`?

Comment: Thanks much, seems like when passing value from a variable I have to wrap it into '"' + messageId + '"'.. 
Still don't fully understand why it didn't work, messageId is read from mysql string field..

Comment: @kuz8 Glad I could help. Clicking on the check mark on the left of my answer would be nice...